# How to check cin after already processed?

Tags: c++, validation, input, cin

What's the best way to check an input if there needs to be processed something before checking another criteria?
code snippet:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <dirent.h>

bool has_suffix(const std::string &str, const std::string &suffix);

void get_path_get_exit(std::string &path_input);


int main()
{
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *ent;
    std::string path_input;
    std::getline(std::cin, path_input);



    const char *path = path_input.c_str();
    dir = opendir(path);
check:
    while ((dir) == NULL && !path_input.empty()){
        /* could not open directory */

        std::cout << "Whoops, that didn't work. Please enter a valid directory path." << std::endl << "-->";
        std::getline(std::cin, path_input);

        path = path_input.c_str();
        closedir(dir);
        dir = opendir(path);
    }
    if ((dir) != NULL) {

        unsigned int counter = 0;

        while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL) {
            counter++;
        }
    /*check if the folder is empty*/ 
        if (counter == 0){
        /*how to surpass the goto statement?*/
            goto check;
        }
        std::string files[counter];


        closedir(dir);
        dir = opendir(path);
        counter = 0;
        while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL) {

                files[counter] = ent->d_name;
                std::cout << "[" << counter+1 << "] " << files[counter] << std::endl;
                counter++;

        }
        closedir(dir);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to check the cin input and in the next if statement I'm trying to check, if the opened directory is empty. Is there any better way to "hop" to the beginning of the top 'check' in order to get into the while loop again and check the new input with the upper criteria again?
Goto does indeed work, but I feel a little ashamed using it.

Comment: shouldn't be `!path_input.empty()` in while condition?

Comment: Of course, sorry I copied it wrong. I've corrected it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract a function which checks condition. This is what good programmers do in such situations.

```
bool IsDirectoryValidForThisOperation(DIR *dir, std::string& failDesdcription)
{
    if (!dir) {
         failDesdcription = "Invalid directory";
         return false;
    }
    if (readdir(dir)) == NULL) {
         failDesdcription = "Directory is empty";
         return false;
    }
    // TODO: restore state of dir

    return true;
}
```

A good code is always spited into small functions, since:

- it is easier to read
- many parts fo code can be reused in another context
- it is easier to write tests
- it is easier to debug
- code will be self documenting

Comment: Thank you. I will take a closer look at it!

Comment: Got it working, just had to add the while loop above to the bool function because dirent.h also recognizes    .    and     ..    as files. So I had to check the suffix.

Answer (score 0):

I might not be understanding your problem perfectly but i sounds like you need a do..while loop

```
    const char *path = path_input.c_str();
    dir = opendir(path);
    do
    {
        while (//some criteria that aren't met){
           /* could not open directory */

           std::cout << "Whoops, that didn't work. Please enter a valid directory path." << std::endl << "-->";
           std::getline(std::cin, path_input);

           path = path_input.c_str();
           closedir(dir);
           dir = opendir(path);
       }
       if ((dir) != NULL) {

           unsigned int counter = 0;

           while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL) {
               counter++;
           }
    /*check if the folder is empty*/
   } while(counter == 0)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think you got me wrong. My question is, how to hop to before the first check was made so the new input is being validated also by the upper requirements.